# Retrieve output from body executed with call in Prolog

Tags: lambda, prolog, meta-predicate

Suppose we have a predicate `p/2` that does something similar to this:

```
p('an atom', OutputList) :-
  some_predicate_1,
  some_predicate_2,
  ...
  findall(...,...,OutputList).
```

`p/2` does something arbitrarly complex and in the end put some result in OutputList.

Suppose I need to have the body of the predicate `p/2` in a list:
`Body = [some_predicate_1,...,findall(...,...,OutputList)]` and I want to execute it.

If I do something like `call(Body)`, how can I retrieve `OutputList`?

Is there any other predicate I can use?

Maybe `call/1` or `call/2` are not right for this purpose.

Comment: Easy to do: In addition to the list of goals, also keep track of the variable so that you can easily refer to it. For example, use a pair like `OutputList-[some_predicate_1,...,findall(...,...,OutputList)]`. Then, after `maplist(call, Ls)` (where `Ls` is the second part of this pair, i.e., the list of goals), you can refer to `OutputList`, which is easily available as the first term of the pair. This is a quite general solution for such problems. You only need to keep track of the variables you want to refer to later. Notice the similarity of such structures to actual Prolog rules by the way!

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure I can do that. I have to use the variable Body like call(Body). I can not istantiate it to its actual predicates because they can be arbitrary.

Comment: No matter, you can still use a pair like `OutputList-Body`, and after `call(Body)`, you can refer to `OutputList`. However, I strongly recommend a clean representation as a *list of goals*, which is also what you indicate in your question. In your question, `Body` is a *list*, and you call these goals for example with `maplist(call, Goals)`. This is a much better representation, because it is not defaulty.

Answer (score 0):

could be easy as

```
get_output_list(Predicates, Outputlist) :-
  last(Predicates, findall(_,_,Outputlist)),
  maplist(call, Predicates).
```

if findall/3 isn't always the last one, this should work

```
get_output_list(Predicates, Outputlist) :-
  maplist(call, Predicates),
  member(findall(_,_,Outputlist), Predicates).
```

in case there could be more than one findall in Predicates, placing member/2 after maplist/2 will get all Outputlist on backtracking

Comment: Thanks, but I can not make the assumption that the result is given always as the last clause.

Comment: Thank you again. Almost, the result is not bound to be in a findall though, but it is always the second parameter of the head of the rule p/2. I could get that with clause/2, but I do not know how to bound it with OutputList after I have executed all the predicates in the body (also I have Body as a variable, it is not bound with its actual predicates because they can differ and I can not predict the structure in advance).

Comment: clause/2 doesn't seems really appropriate... maybe you should clarify further what you expect. Doesn't seems to match with your question.